# Temporally disable password to login with empty password?

Tags: login, password, wp-login-form

Does someone knows what part of wordpress code would I have to modify to be able to just enter into the admin panel without having to login?

I need to work on a site but I wont have admin access until a few day (when my friend comes back from vacations), but I do have FTP access (only FTP, no cpanel or any other type of panel to get into the db and change the pwd) and have his permissions to do whatever I need to login.

I checked wp-login.php file but couldn't find what to modify to allow me to login.

Does someone knows what file shoul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it, but this thread on stackoverflow.com seems to be what you need - [Create new admin, wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4199046)

Comment: Thanks that looks good, but the linked site containing the required db class doesn't seem to be working. I will see if I can reproduce what it does without that.

Comment: I am having troubles retrieving the inserted new ID, I found db class on google and I am trying to reproduce what you showed me, here's the code : http://pastie.org/private/noxfa5lhmcqhgxa6oh6bq do you know how to retrieve the new inserted user id?

Comment: mysql_insert_id() function worked

Comment: If this was your solution, please mark it accordingly so that anyone who finds this question and has the same issue can benefit from your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: The following script should only be used in a **local** development environment.

Maybe you can try the auto-login script, just copy the code below to a php file like autologin.php,and put the file in the root directory, then navigate to 
http://yoursite.com/autologin.php and you will be logged in automatically as administrator

```
<?php
require('wp-blog-header.php');
$query_str = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users";
$user_ids = $wpdb->get_results( $query_str);
foreach (  $user_ids as $uid ) {
    $user_id = $uid->ID;
    if( user_can($user_id, 'administrator') ){
        $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
        $user_login = $user_info->user_login;
        wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
        do_action('wp_login', $user_login);
        echo "You are logged in as $user_login";
        if( function_exists('get_admin_url') ){
            wp_redirect( get_admin_url() );
        } else {
            wp_redirect( get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-admin' );
        }
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

BTW, the sql query is not necessory if you know the user ID of administrator

Comment: Not at all, actually I was thinking to add the comment about using it carefully:), thank you!